# Android Retrofit - Callback vs no call back

Tags: android, retrofit, square

I am analyzing retrofit on android and had a question on callbacks vs not using them.  I am under the impression that callbacks are only used for success and failure responses a client might desire.  Otherwise i would omit it.  Here is an example of a retrofit interface without a callback:

```
 public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

and here is an example with a callback (i hope i have it right):

```
   public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user,Callback<Repo> cb);
}
```

Im confused on two things:

1. The return value in the interface is List but to me it should be void because retrofit will use gson to convert the json response to a Repo POJO. All i have to do is create the Repo POJO so i would expect the last piece of code to be like this instead:

   public interface GitHubService {

   @GET("/users/{user}/repos")

   **void** listRepos(@Path("user") String user,Callback cb);
               }

What is the purpose of the return value?

2. my second question is : is the callback only necessary to know if the request was a success or failure as i see from the docs that callback has two methods: failure and success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to try and answer your question*

*1. You are correct, the return value should be `void`, as you will get the response from the `Callback`*

*2. Yes it is, the `Callback` is needed to check whether the request is successful or not, also it is there to grab the server response.*

*Hope this is useful, cheers!*

---

**EDIT** : You can use direct return value or use callbacks to get the response. Quoting from the retrofit documentation site :

- A method with a return type will be executed synchronously.
- Asynchronous execution requires the last parameter of the method be a Callback.

So I guess the documentation answers it really, Callback is needed if you want the execution to be asynchronous :D

Comment: this is great confirmation thanks.  But if you check the examples here http://square.github.io/retrofit/  you'll see  in the very first example they are using a return type of List<Repo> instead of void. How is the return type used.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer, check it out, I got the answer from the `Synchronous vs. Asynchronous vs. Observable` part of the documentation on their site :D

Comment: if you dont pass a callback, you have to catch a RetrofitError otherwise your code will crash when any sort of error occurrs

Comment: @The-null-Pointer- Where and how can I catch the Retrofit exceptions if I can't use callbacks? I tried the intercept function of an Interceptor but there I have to deliver a response that I don't have when an exception occured. If I don't a null pointer exception is thrown by Retrofit.